# Is 'volare-karaoke.swf' a malware?

Tags: macos, malware, adobe-flash

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12. I've noticed an unwanted file `volare-karaoke.swf` automatically getting download from both Safari and FireFox. It happens mostly when I'm on financial/payment sites (HSBC/Tesco Bank etc.) and less so on other sites. I trash it whenever I encounter it in my Downloads folder.

After extensive Google search I can find no reference to it being malware (and Malwarebytes doesn't detect it). I don't use an antivirus utility apart from Malwarebytes. Neither browser flags danger.

I'm convinced it's malicious.

Does anyone have any info about the file and its nature and why is it downloaded automatically?

the link destination for the 'volare-karaoke.swf malware = http://(XXX my 3 XXX)fun.from.hell.pl/2003-02-18/volare-karaoke.swf

Comment: `.swf` files are Shockwave Flash.  I highly doubt HSBC/Tesco are sending you this file.  Create a new user profile and navigate to their site - do you still get the download?  If not, there's an issue with your profile that needs looking into.

Comment: is that before or after you log in ?

Comment: Hi Alan, welcome to Ask Different. This behavior is not normal... After being downloaded from Safari, if you press the download icon on the right side of the toolbar, is the `.swf` file displayed there? If that's the case, right-click the `.swf` entry and select copy address. Does the URL come from HSBC/Tesco Bank, etc? Or does it have another domain? Could you post the URL (put some spaces to prevent it from becoming clickable).